# Granting APP authorization to Google Drive files

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to authorize files on my google drive with specific APP authorization I created. As files on my google drive can only be manipulated by its authorized app, is there any way I can convert these "None" authorized file with APP authorization? And, if yes, by which function?

I looked all over the tutorial document but only find discussion about permission. The only method I can think about is uploading these files to google drive with upload function from my created app. But I guess there is a much smarter way. Do any one has the same experience?

Here list my steps to create authorized file:

- First, I start my app from using sample code, DrEdit. https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python;
- From the code, I successfully open new files and saw them listed on my google drive.
- From view authorized app, I can clear see these apps created from my app have their authorization signed with app ID. The other files original belong to me have these authorization signed as "None".

Comment: I have the similar problem. Was using the DrEdit app too and my problem was how to edit the created text file outside of the app. I think google drive doesn't permit you to edit the file online, rather its available as read only. I tried uploading a text file but the app cannot see it because there's no authorized app assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to change the scope from https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive which gives full access to all drive files rather than just the ones created by the app.